# How to stream audio from a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was trying to make a chrome extension for streaming audio peer to peer, using WebRTC but the thing is since the extension is going to be alive for a while, I tried sending the peer connection data and the description as local to get the local audio and I did the same for the remote audio.

```
async function addStreamtoPeerConnection(pc) {
    await chrome.extension.sendMessage({ type: "local", pc: pc });
}

// Remote  audio which is created after the above function and the connection was initialized
friends[pub].pc.ontrack = (event) => {
        console.log("ontrack", event);
        if (remoteAudio.src !== event.streams) {
            //createResonanceScence(event.streams[0]);

            chrome.extension.sendMessage({ type: "remote", event: event });
            console.log("received remote stream", event);
        }
    };
```

And after recieving the requests the background script was supposed to create the audio elements and play them from the background.

```
document.write(
    "<div class='audioComponent'><audio class='localAudio'></audio><audio class='remoteAudio'></audio></div>"
);
var localAudio = document.getElementsByClassName(".localAudio");
var remoteAudio = document.getElementsByClassName(".remoteAudio");
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, response) => {
    console.log("Req:", request);
    if (request.type == "local") {
        var constraints = { audio: true, video: false };
        navigator.mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia(constraints)
            .then((userMediaStream) => {
                userMediaStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
                    request.pc.addTrack(track, userMediaStream);
                });
                localAudio.src = userMediaStream;
                localAudio.onloadedmetadata = function () {
                    localAudio.play();
                    console.log(">>>>LOCAL AUDIO HERE<<<<<");
                    localAudio.muted = true;
                };
                localAudio.attr("disabled", true);
            });

        console.log(document.getElementsByClassName(".audioComponent"));
    }
    if (request.type == "remote") {
        remoteAudio.muted = true;
        createResonanceScence(request.event.streams);
        remoteAudio.src = request.event.streams;
        remoteAudio.onloadedmetadata = function () {
            remoteAudio.play();
            console.log("metadata loaded");
        };
        document.getElementsByClassName(".audioComponent").append(remoteAudio);
    }
});
```

_generated_background_page.html:1 Error in event handler: TypeError: localAudio.play is not a function
at chrome-extension://pckefmohphiekioecgigmahpganhhjfg/src/js/background.js:26:14

_generated_background_page.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed due to shutdown

The above are the errors I get from the background page

Comment: localAudio returns an array as document.getElementsByClassName always returns array.
Try replacing localAudio with localAudio[0]

Comment: It fixed one of the errors which was localAudio.play is not a function, but its still giving the DOMException error and it might be because of the promise in navigator.mediaDevices